# How to set the length, breath of outer div in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two element. a div inside a another div. i want to set length and breath of the outer div. the inner div has class name?
something like below html

```html
<div>
  <div class='innerdiv'>
    hello inner div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <bod>
<div>
<div class = 'innerdiv'>
hello inner div
</div>
</div>
</body>

Comment: Added a possible solution for you to try using `jQuery`.  Got to pop out but hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0):

I see you have `jQuery` tagged so I'll use it in my example.  I'm just going to select the div by class name, then traverse to it's parent element (the outer div), then apply css changes to it:

```
$('.innerDiv').parent().css({
    "width": "800px",
    "height": "300px"
});
```

That should do the job for you.  You can obviously include other CSS propertiers in there too

edit:  forgot to mention, if you have multiple sets of these div, inner divs, you might consider giving them IDs and targetting those

Answer (score 0):

You first access the parent node. And then assign width and height properties to it. For your example html code

```
var parentNode = document.getElementsByClassName('innerdiv')[0].parentNode;
parentNode.style.height = "100px";
parentNode.style.width = "100px";
```

Comment: Thanx thapa, its working. I was not using 0 index thats why undefined coming. But now working fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try using parentNode method js. You can get target div ( child ) with getElementsByClassName()[0] and then on the same you can apply node.parentNode method to get the desired result.

Hope it helps

Comment: I did this 
document.getElementsByClassName('innerdiv').parentNode
but it does not help me.

Comment: How does using `parentNode` help with retrieving the width and height of an element? This appear to be half an answer at best

Comment: Hi, Rory can you complete the answer?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan he wants to _set_ the dimensions, not get them